# Vkontakte: get big profile image with passport.js

Tags: javascript, passport.js, vk

In passport.js, I retrieve vkontakte profile picture like this:

```
newUser.vkontakte.image = profile.photos[0].value;
```

This gives me the smallest picture size. How can I get the original size?

I did try things like

```
newUser.vkontakte.image = profile.photo_200;
```

or

```
newUser.vkontakte.image = params.photo_200;
```

but response was empty. Just in case, I changed scope like this:

```
'friends, photos, email, photo_200'
```

Answer (score 0):

When I get profile photo url like this

> http://pbs.tw........32735322/afY8luRq_normal.jpeg.

I substring "_normal". It's will get original image size

> http://pbs.tw........32735322/afY8luRq.jpeg.